# Injecting more than one properties file into a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Right now I'm using [EnvInject plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to insert my environment variables through a properties file into my Jenkins job.

However, now I have a second job which needs the same environment variables as the first job and than some more additional variables which I would like to load via another properties file.

I know, there is a possibility to insert the values via Properties Content Edit field of the EnvInject-plugin, but I would like to keep it in a file, so it can be shared between jobs. But there seems to be no possibility to add a second properties file to EnvInject-plugin.

Is there any way to inject more than one properties file into a job or any other plugin, that could handle my scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple way to get around the limitation you have.
You should load each file in the **Build** section, as a build step.
Use the **Inject environment variables** build step, and load each file you want. You can add multiple files by setting up multiple build steps of this type.

This works well for me on a similar need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) to config some shell scripts.
You can add multiple files and then execute them.